# Another way proof $1/2-1/3=1/6$ by using picture?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, alternative-proof

We know that $\dfrac{1}{2} -\dfrac{1}{3} =\dfrac{1}{6}$. I proved it by picture
[image]
What is (are) another way (ways) by using picture?

Comment: I mean... instead of a rectangle you could pick a circle and cut it in a 6-piece pie

Comment: Directly from the definition of addition and subtraction of fractions is another way.

Comment: Or have $6$ dots (arbitrary object) in total. Isolate $3$, subtract $2$, you get $1$.

Comment: Instead of using a rectangle I suppose you could always use a regular hexagon and take advantage of its 6-fold rotational symmetry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a nice picture, using an equilateral triangle, because the shape has both 2-way and 3-way symmetry. Each large right triangle is 1/2, and each kite is 1/3.
[image]

Is this the kind of thing you were looking for?

Comment: An isoceles triangle with base on one side of the larger triangle and apex at the center of the larger triangle also 1/3 the area of the large triangle; same result.

Answer (score 5):

Primary school teachers generally use pattern blocks.

Show that the green [1/6] plus the blue [1/3] equals the red [1/2].

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The assertion is true in any commutative ring where the multiplicative inverses exist, even though you can't always draw a picture.

$1/a$ is the solution to the equation $ax = 1$ so

$$
6 \left( \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} \right)
=
2 \times 3 \times \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) - 2 \times 3 \times\left( \frac{1}{3} \right)
= 3 - 2 = 1
$$
so the expression  on the left in the question is the multiplicative inverse of $6$.

(This is the core of the rule for adding fractions.)

Comment: I want to proof by using picture. Please read my question.

Comment: @Ethan any mention of commutative rings in the context of fractions [makes me think of this](https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/2014-12-06)

Answer (score 0):

I think that an other useful picture could be the disk.
We can divide in two pieces the disk, of course at 180° and in the same way we can divide it in 3 pieces at 120°. At this point is simple to show what remains, and also the computation of the difference.